# How to change JButton Icon when selected?

Tags: java, swing, applet, icons, jbutton

I Want to change the JButton icon when user press/release the button.

A icon image when the JButton were selected

[image]

A icon image when the JButton were unselected and the JButton were release:

[image: When unselected/release]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
JButton b = new JButton(Icon x); // Create button with normal icon
   b.setIcon(Icon x);
   b.setDisabledIcon(Icon x);
   b.setPressedIcon(Icon x);
   b.setSelectedIcon(Icon x);
   b.setDisabledSelectedIcon(Icon x);
```

ref: 
http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/components/20buttons/23buttonicons.html

Comment: @BernardoVale reading the api doc helps to minimize those moments of feeling dumb :-)